# Not able to execute Spring Boot Jar into Production Web Sphere 8.5 server

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-8

I have a Spring Boot '1.5.1.RELEASE' jar File . I am able to execute the jar using `java -jar 'jar Name'` on my local And able to launch the application on my local.

But when i execute the same jar File in WAAS 8.5 , I get `There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
AuthConfigFactory error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry` on browser.

And below exception in server
`java.lang.SecurityException: AuthConfigFactory error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry
java.lang.SecurityException: AuthConfigFactory error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry
        at javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory.getFactory(AuthConfigFactory.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.getJaspicProvider(AuthenticatorBase.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1177) [na:1.7.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) [na:1.7.0]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:857) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.ProviderRegistry`

I tried using 
`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`
but it did not help.

PS : I want it to execute as a jar file instead of a war file.

my pom.xml file

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.scb.com</groupId>
<artifactId>BatchDashBoard</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>DashBoard</name>
<description>DashBoard For the Batch Processing</description>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
<version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.2.14.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
<java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: You cannot "run" a jar inside a servlet container, it has to be a war or ear.

Comment: Why not sir ? I was able to start the jar , but the error was while accessing the URL .

I managed to solve it , it was the issue with the JRE of the Web sphere server. 

My application was developed and compiled on Oracle JRE , but on the Web sphere server it was IBM jre.. So there was a mismatch of the JRE..

Managed to fix and run..Thank you

Comment: You can only deploy spring-boot as `wars`, otherwise you are not deploying it to WebSphere, but just run as java apps. Check this page for tutorial - http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/java/spring-boot/deploy-spring-boot-application-ibm-liberty-8-5/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think WebSphere does not let you run a java main program in WAS JDK.

Comment: You were right if you meant the jar file compiled in different JRE's ( Oracle & IBM ) .

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it.

Web Sphere had only IBM supported JRE installed. And My application was built and compiled using Oracle supported JRE.

So it was JRE mismatch issue.